# DockerToolbox1.11.2.exe Not running on 64bit Win7

Tags: windows, docker

Unable to run DockerToolbox1.11.2.exe in Windows7.
 Tried running the installer using admin privileges, wont run. Task manager  status shows not responding.

Could it be corporate proxy settings?

- I have 64bit Windows7 laptop.
- Verified Hardware assisted
  virtualization is enabled on this computer

Answer (score 0):

Try the alternative: [docker machine v0.8.0-rc2](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/tag/v0.8.0-rc2)

All you need to do is:

- download [`docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.8.0-rc2/docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe),
- rename it in `docker-machine.exe` somewhere on your %PATH%,
- type `doskey dm=docker-machine.exe $*`
- then type '`dm`' (that will display the help)

From there you can start creating docker machines.